# Can't add another "Page Content" box

Tags: page-layout, content

I've attempted to add a column on the page to add more content (it displays each column as "page content" in a box).

I do this by going to "`edit properties`" on the page, then scrolling down to the third "`page content`" area, then attempting to add content there.

When I put anything in there, it just doesn't show up on the page after I save.

Comment: please mention more tags related to your question like SharePoint version , page layout ...etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing such problem then save your data and exit it then after 2 3 mins again open the file and then add "Page Content" box. I hope now your problem is resolved.